# mkdir(), get path from form

Tags: php, forms, input, directory, mkdir

I have a form, where I submit the data to `$_POST['foldername']`

`createdir.php` below

```
<form action="mkdir.php">
    <input type="textarea" name="foldername" id="foldername">
    <input type="submit" value="Create directory">
</form>
```

Then I have `mkdir()` that should have a path including the name got from a input field, but the problem is, that it doesn't get the data from input. I tried to print it as well, but all I get is `/images/` but I should (at least I hope to) get `/images/nameFromInput`.

`mkdir.php` below

```
<?php
$foldername = $_POST['foldername'];

$path = 'images/' . $foldername;
mkdir($path);
header('Location:createdir.php')
?>
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: There is no input type "textarea", just "text".

Comment: @HugoDelsing True, but unrecognized input types are treated as text, so that's probably not causing his problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action="mkdir.php" method="POST">
```

You forgot the method.

Answer (score 0):

Even if in the last line isn't required, You forgot the semicolon at the end.
This could drive you crazy... so I suggest you always to append it!

```
header('Location: createdir.php');
```

Also, `type="textarea"` doesn't exists, use: `type="text"` or `<textarea>`.

Comment: You're right about the HTML error but the semicolon at the end is not a mistake - `The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block.`

Comment: Mate, I know! :) I'm not saying that is an error, just saying that could become it! You just add new line after it (like an `exit()`) and everything crashes. Millions of question here are about dumb errors like that! I was just suggesting a code practice. I usually  don't append a semicolon only with `<?= $var ?>`. Just my opinion!